# Restrict spaces from input in console

Tags: c++, if-statement, input, while-loop, cin

I have 3 cin for ints.

```
int input1;
cin >> input;

int input2;
cin >> input2;

int input3
cin >> input3;
```

The problem is if i type `2 3 4` in console, it will input all 3 in one shot. How can i prevent this? And possibly give them a warning if they do this. basically error input validating.

Answer (score 0):

You may do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    while(true) {
        std::cout << "Enter a number [Enter to quit]: ";
        std::string line;
        getline(std::cin, line);
        if(line.empty()) break;
        else {
            std::stringstream input(line);
            int number;
            // Preceding white space number trailing white space:
            input >> number >> std::ws;
            if(input && input.eof()) {
                std::cout
                    << "The number surronded by possible white space is: "
                    << number
                    << '\n';
            }
            else {
                std::cout
                    << "The input line is invalid: "
                    << line
                    << '\n';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want to be strict:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

...

// Number without preceding and trailing white space:
input >> std::noskipws >> number;

...
```